# WebGL vs CSS3D for large scatter plot of images

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am building a web application which will display a large number of image thumbnails as a 3D cloud and provide the ability to click on individual images to launch a large view.  I have successfully done this in CSS3D using three.js by creating a THREE.CSS3DObject for each thumbnail and then append the thumbnail as an svg:image.

It works great for upto ~1200 thumbnails and then performance starts to drop off (very low FPS and long load time).  By the time you hit 2500 thumbnails it is unusable.  Ideally I want to work with over 10k thumbnails.

From what I can tell I would be able to achieve the same result by creating each thumbnail as a WebGL mesh with texture.  I am a beginner with three.js though, so before I put in the effort I was hoping for guidance on whether I can expect performance to be better or am I just asking too much of 3D in the browser?

Comment: given that there's full blown 3d engines [running in browsers](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2014/03/12/mozilla-and-epic-preview-unreal-engine-4-running-in-firefox/), 2500 thumbnails isn't very much at all.

Comment: That was my thought too - I was surprised at the performance.  It is entirely possible there is something inefficient in my code.

Comment: 2500 thumbnails will kill perf. The way game engines run fast is BY OPTIMIZING WHAT THEY DRAW! They draw as little as possible. They combine textures into text atlases, they combine meshes into large meshes. They get their draw calls down to a < 5000, [often under 1000](http://www.adriancourreges.com/blog/2015/03/10/deus-ex-human-revolution-graphics-study/). So, if you want to display 10k images you're going to need to combine meshes and combine textures. Even native assembly will not do well with 10k individual textures and 10k draw calls.

Comment: I would suggest using sprites instead of CSS3D elements.  Create your sprite textures using HTML5 canvas methods.  You should be able to scale way higher than 2.5k.

Comment: Sprites was the answer!  I just switched to using sprites and WebGLRenderer and 10K thumbnails is no problem at all!  I did lose all my interactivity though, but I think it is fixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as rendering goes, CSS3 should be relatively okay for rendering quite big amount of "sprites". But 10k would probably be too much.

WebGL would probably be a better option though. You could also take care about further optimizations, storing thumbnails in atlas texture or such...

But rendering is just one part. Event handling can be serious bottleneck if not handled carefully.

I don't know how you're handling mouse clock event and transition towards fullsize image, but attaching event listener to each of 2.5k+ objects probably isn't a good choice anyway. With pure WebGL you could use imagespace for detecting clicked object. Encoding each tile with different id/color and using that to determine what's clicked. I imagine that WebGL/CSS3D combo could use this approach as well.

To answer question, WebGL should handle 10k fine. Maybe you'll need to think about some perf optimization if your rectangles are big and they take a significant amount on the screen, but there are ways around it if that problem appears.

Comment: I am using raycasting to figure out if mouse clicks intersect with objects, which I think is more efficient that attaching event listeners as you say.